# Read data image, upload from web and save them in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm newest in ruby on rails developpement and i would like what is the best way to save an pictures/image from the controller of my web page. I try with something like this:

```
@fin = File.open(params[:photos] , "rb")
@img = @fin.read
```

I think you have understand my reasoning. At the end I want to be able to save my picture into my database.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use a gem like carrierwave: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

You really should not save a picture into a database. Instead you should store the image on some sort of other datastore and put a pointer to it in your database. Carrierwave makes this very easy and has different adapters to store the images on your local filesystem, S3, SFTP, or NFS.

Thoughtbot's Paperclip is another good alternative: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: Paperclip is fantastic. Highly recommend.